# Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass') error with "cross_val_score" function from sklearn.model_selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have 2 datasets train and test:

```
print(f"""{type(X_train)} {X_train.shape}""")
print(f"""{type(Y_train)} {Y_train.shape}""")
print(f"""{type(Y_train.iloc[:,0])} {Y_train.iloc[:,0].shape}""")
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (531456, 6)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (531456, 1)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> (531456,)
```

I get ValueError:
Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead.
when I call cross_val_score function from sklearn.model_selection.

It looks like parameters types are not good.
I have a:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (531456, 6) for X_train
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (531456, 1) for _train that I transform to a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> (531456,) for cross_valscore.

```
cross_val_score(SVC(random_state=random_state), X_train, y=Y_train.iloc[:,0], scoring='accuracy', cv=kfold, n_jobs=4)
```

I dont' know what happens.
If you can help me please.
Thanks a lot.
Théo

Full log:

```
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    807             try:
--> 808                 tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    809             except queue.Empty:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\queue.py in get(self, block, timeout)
    166                 if not self._qsize():
--> 167                     raise Empty
    168             elif timeout is None:

Empty: 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-8f14ca49d3fa> in <module>
----> 1 cross_val_score(SVC(random_state=random_state), X_train, y=Y_train.iloc[:,0], scoring='accuracy', cv=kfold, n_jobs=4)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    399     scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
    400 
--> 401     cv_results = cross_validate(estimator=estimator, X=X, y=y, groups=groups,
    402                                 scoring={'score': scorer}, cv=cv,
    403                                 n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    240     parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,
    241                         pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
--> 242     scores = parallel(
    243         delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    244             clone(estimator), X, y, scorers, train, test, verbose, None,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1027             # remaining jobs.
   1028             self._iterating = False
-> 1029             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1030                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1031 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    817                 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
    818 
--> 819                 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    820                 if len(islice) == 0:
    821                     return False

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    240     parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,
    241                         pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
--> 242     scores = parallel(
    243         delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    244             clone(estimator), X, y, scorers, train, test, verbose, None,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
    334                 .format(self.n_splits, n_samples))
    335 
--> 336         for train, test in super().split(X, y, groups):
    337             yield train, test
    338 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
     78         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
     79         indices = np.arange(_num_samples(X))
---> 80         for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
     81             train_index = indices[np.logical_not(test_index)]
     82             test_index = indices[test_index]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _iter_test_masks(self, X, y, groups)
    695 
    696     def _iter_test_masks(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
--> 697         test_folds = self._make_test_folds(X, y)
    698         for i in range(self.n_splits):
    699             yield test_folds == i

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _make_test_folds(self, X, y)
    647         allowed_target_types = ('binary', 'multiclass')
    648         if type_of_target_y not in allowed_target_types:
--> 649             raise ValueError(
    650                 'Supported target types are: {}. Got {!r} instead.'.format(
    651                     allowed_target_types, type_of_target_y))

ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead.
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback. In this case, a sample of the data in `Y_train` may also be helpful.

Comment: Hi I updated my question with full error traceback. In Y_train, I have only 2 differents values: 1 with  278 706 samples and 0 with 252 750 samples.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: cross_val_score function worked fine in a previous project in which X_train and Y_train file were generated by a model_selection.train_test_split function. X_train was a 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' and Y_train was a 
'pandas.core.series.Series'.

Comment: It's was why in my code for parameter Y in cross_val_score function, I pass a DataFrame converted to a Series by y=Y_train.iloc[:,0].

Comment: can you check the dtype of y column?

Comment: Y_train is a pandas.core.series.Series type and its dtype is int64

Comment: it should work... really hard to tell what went wrong. Last guess, how did you define kfold? I think its very hard to know unless you share some small part of the data?

Comment: You can see from the traceback that the problem is with `Y_train`, and that `sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target` is returning `"unknown"` instead of `"binary"` as you'd expect.  Without having `Y_train` then, we can't diagnose it.  First, check the above claim by directly calling `type_of_target(Y_train)`.  Then, maybe step through [the logic of that function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/38e6022e24e1a3c91f932fec87302ffc0610651b/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L250) to see where exactly it goes wrong.

Comment: OK I'm starting to undestand my error: with kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10): call of  cross_val_score(SVC(random_state=random_state), X_train, y=Y_train.iloc[:,0], scoring='accuracy', cv=kfold, n_jobs=4) produces the error. But if I call the same function with parameter cv=5 for example => no error but as result I get an  array with 5 nan values!!! ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]). Same output if I call the function with Y parameter value directly Y_train (Dataframe) and cv=5 . Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: the type of X_train's columns with a float values was an object an not a float64 type.

```
X_train.dtypes 
AccX    object
AccY    object
AccZ    object
GyrX    object
GyrY    object
GyrZ    object
dtype: object
```

So after a conversion of theses columns 's type to float64, it works fine now.

> ```
> X_train = X_train.apply(lambda col:pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce'))
> AccX    float64
> AccY    float64
> AccZ    float64
> GyrX    float64
> GyrY    float64
> GyrZ    float64
> ```

Same thing on the Y_train target column  (binary value) to convert columns 's type to int type.